# if and cond in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I figured out how to use if statements in scheme, but not quite sure of how to use cond here. I need to change both if to cond. Any suggestions?

```
(define (pi err)
  (let loop ([n 0]
             [p +nan.0]
             [c 0.0])
    (if (< (abs (- c p)) (/ err 4))
        (* 4 p)
        (loop (add1 n)
              c
              ((if (even? n) + -) c (/ 1 (+ 1 n n)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one predicate and a then and else expression you won't get any benefits of converting it to a `cond`, but it is very easy:

```
(if predicate-expression
    then-expression
    else-expression)
```

is the same as:

```
(cond
  (predicate-expression then-expression)
  (else else-expression))
```

Using your `if` example it becomes:

```
(cond
  ((< (abs (- c p)) (/ err 4)) (* 4 p))
  (else (loop ...)))
```

It's much more interesting if you have nested if like this:

```
(if predicate-expression
    then-expression
    (if predicate2-expression
        then2-expression
        else-expression))
```

which turns flatter and usually easier:

```
(cond
  (predicate-expression then-expression)
  (predicat2e-expression then2-expression)
  (else else-expression))
```